# Create CSV file using Apache PO API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have an requirement to create CSV file on some configuration basis.

Example

1. From configuration master we are defining the header of file so while creation a file use this header and show only this header values in each column.
2. Headers may change so basically it is creation of csv file dynamically.

is it possible in CSV?

Please help me in this.

Comment: `Apache poi` is not made to create `CSV` files. In `Excel` context `apache poi` creates either `*.xls` or `*.xlsx` files but not `*.csv` files.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. This is based on the assumption that you are supplying a list containing JSONObjects.

```
private String generateCSVWithDynamicHeaders(List<JSONObject> listToPrint) throws Exception {
    XSSFRow row = null;
    try {
        if (listToPrint.size() < 1) return "You sent an empty list";
        //Convert set to list. Alternatively you can just use iterator and leave this as a set.
        List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>(listToPrint.get(0).keySet());
        //Set row number where the headings will start from
        int rowNum = 1;
        //Excel / CSV creation
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Dynamic CSV");
        row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);

        //Set headers here
        for (int h = 0; h < headers.size(); h++) {
            row.createCell(h).setCellValue(headers.get(h));
        }

        //Increment row number such that the header is not over written
        rowNum += 1;
        //Print values after headers are done
        for (JSONObject object : listToPrint) {
            //Create a new row per iteration
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
            for (int h = 0; h < headers.size(); h++) {
                row.createCell(h).setCellValue(object.getString(headers.get(h)));
            }
            rowNum += 1;
        }
        String fileName = "Dynamic Sheet";
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("./location-to-write-file-to/" + fileName + ".csv");
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        return "We are good";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Unable to generate dymanic CSV");
    }
}
```

Comment: No I am passing List of Java DTO object

Comment: Why use POI? A CSV file is just a text file…
Maybe a CSV api *if necessary*…

Comment: @SantoshKshirsagar What are you passing?

Comment: I have created FileDataDTO have fields of file